# Как перебрать массив и произвести мат действия над сопадениями?

Tags: php

Добрый день, есть два массива, такого формата. Нужно перебрать массив и если в первом и втором массиве есть совпадения ключа, например [Вася] то, отнять значение [Вася][count], первого массива от[Вася][count] второго массива. И так для всех ключей если они совпадают, т.е. они есть и в первом массиве и во втором. А если нет совпадений, то удаляем.

```
//Первый массив:

    Array
    (
        [Вася] => Array
            (
    [id] => 123
    [count] => 1000
    )
        [Петя] => Array
            (
    [id] => 321
    [count] => 2000
    )
    )

//Второй массив

    Array
    (
        [Вася] => Array
            (
    [id] => 123
    [count] => 700
    )
        [Петя] => Array
            (
    [id] => 321
    [count] => 500
    )
[Слава] => Array
            (
    [id] => 454
    [count] => 800
    )
    )
```

В результате надо получить третий массив, где добавленно новое ключ значение [result_count] с произведенными нами арифмет. манипуляциями. И удаленным [Слава] т.к. его нет в одном из массивов.

```
    Array
    (
        [Вася] => Array
            (
    [id] => 123
    [count] => 1000
[result_count] => 300
    )
        [Петя] => Array
            (
    [id] => 321
    [count] => 2000
[result_count] => 1500
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ar3=array();
foreach($ar1 as $k=>$v){
   if(!empty($ar2[$k])
     $ar3[$k]=array(
     'id'=>$v['id'],
     'count'=>$v['count'],
     'result_count'=>$v['count']-$ar2[$k]['count'])
}
```

В $ar3 - Результат

Comment: Спасибо, понял!)